# How to print data from JSON in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, getjson, ionic3

I have created a db in JSON but I can not see the data or get error on the other end but I can se the object in the log.

```
[    {
      "teachers": [
          {
            "img":"assets/inst/J.png",
            "name":"Janine ",
            "bio":"lorem"
          },{
            "img":"assets/insta/I.png",
            "name":"Itzhak",
            "bio":"lorem"
          }
      ]
    }
]
```

Service for fetching the data

```
    homeds: Home[];
  constructor( public dataService: DataProvider) {
    this.dataService.fetchData().subscribe(
           (data) => {
             this.homeds = data}  
         )
  }
```

Lastly my template file is

```
<ion-row class="home" *ngFor="let home of homeds">
 <img src="{{ home.teachers?.img }}" alt="">
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have nested **`ngFor`** since teachers is an array

```
<ion-row class="home" *ngFor="let home of homeds">
 <div   *ngFor="let homeobj of home.teachers ">
   <img src="{{ homeobj?.img }}" alt="">
  </div>
</ion-row>
```